# Visual Studio 2008: Setting the vertical separation to default in wpf designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I favour the vertical separation over the horizontal separation in VS2008 wpf designer.
But after deleting the .suo (fresh checkout, new project, etc.) this setting is gone.
Is there a way to tell visual studio to default to the vertical separation instead of the horizontal for wpf designer ?
I can not find anything in the "options". Did I miss this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unlike in the HTML designer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/enabling-vertical-split-view-in-vs-2008.aspx) of Visual Studio (!) there is currently no way to make the vertical split the default in the XAML designer: [see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/1bdf2ddd-472c-4c17-ad2e-845f5bf1f086). You will always have to set it manually on a per file basis. These settings will indeed be stored in the .suo file. Unfortunately this applies to both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. You can file a request to remove this inconsitency in the next release [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).