# Visual Studio 2010 - Set XAML Designer Display to Vertical

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm looking at designing some applications for Windows Phone 7 using Visual Studio 2010. Each time I create a .XAML file the IDE opens the file up with the designer and the script side-by-side. I would prefer to have them displayed vertically but I can't find the option to do that.

I see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712190/visual-studio-2008-setting-the-vertical-separation-to-default-in-wpf-designer) that it may not actually be possible. Does anyone know if it is in fact possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the center of the screen, at the bottom of the separator between the code view and the designer view, click the button with the horizontal line it to switch to "Horizontal Split".

Comment: Thanks Derek, I probably didn't word my question too well. I know I can change the view once the file is opened using the button you mention but I'd like to have the view default to having the designer on top of the script.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't there's a way to set it by default, but I think it remembers what you chose last time, though that may be on a per-file basis.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it. I will mark your response as the answer.